# Sending and receiving data over Internet

Tags: sockets, send

This question is not for a concrete implementation of how this is done. It is more about the concept and design of sending information over Internet with some kind of protocol - either TCP or UDP. I know only that sockets are needed, but I am wondering about the rest. For example after a connection is made and you send the information through that, but how does the other end listen for a specific port and does it listen constantly?
Is listening done in a background thread waiting for information to be received? (In order to be able to do other things/processing while waiting for information)
So in essence, I think a real world example of how such an application works on a high level would be enough to explain the data flow. For example sending files in Skype or something similar.

P.S. Most other questions on similar topics are about a concrete implementation or a bug that someone has.

Comment: 'Most other questions on similar topics are about a concrete implementation or a bug that someone has' - yes, because those questions are not too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I currently do in an application is the following using POSIX sockets with the TCP Protocol:

Most important thing is: The most function are blocking functions. So when you tell your server to wait for client connection, the function will block until a connection is established (if you need a server that handles multiple clients at once, you need to use threading!)

Server listens for specific port until a client connects. After the connect, you will get a new socket file descriptor to communicate with the client whilst the initial socket can listen to new connections. My server then creats a new thread to handle that client whilst waiting for new connections on the initial socket. In the new thread the server waits for a request command from the Client (e.g. Request Login Token). After a request was received by the server, the server will gather its informations, packs it together using Googles Protocol Buffers and sends it to the client. The client now either tells the server to terminate the session (if every data is received by the client that it needs) or send another request.

Thats basically the idea in my server. The bigger problem is the way you transmit and receive data. E.g. you cant send structs or classes (at least not via C++) over the wire, you need some kind of serializer and you have to make sure the other part knows how much to receive. So what i do is, first send a 4byte integer over the wire containing the size of the incomming package, then send the package itself using a serializer (in my case Googles Protocol buffers). The other side waits for 4 byte to be available, knowing that this will be the size of the incomming package. After 4 bytes are received, the program waits for exact that amount of data being available on the socket, when available, read the data out of the buffer and deserialize it. When the socket is not receiving data for 30 seconds, trigger a timeout and terminate the connection.

What you always need to be aware of is the endianess of the systems. E.g. a big endian system (e.g. PowerPC) and a little endian system (e.g. x86) will have problems when you send an integer directly over the wire. For example a

```
0001
```

on the x86, is a

```
1000
```

on the Power PC, thus making a 8 out of a 1. So you should always use functions like ntohl, an htonl, which will convert data from and to host byte order from and to network byte order (network byte order is always big endian).
Hope this kind of helps. I could also provide some code to you if that would help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This is what I was looking for in an answer. Just to make it more clear, I am guessing that the thread on the server uses an infinite loop that constantly tries to find a connection and when it does - it starts the second thread for the connected client. Is that correct?

P.S. I would upvote your reply but I don't have enough rep, sorry.

Comment: Basically yes. But the connect() function will block until a connection is incomming, so there is no need for putting a thread to sleep. Comes in pretty handy.